# how to parse exception error

Tags: php, exception

I'm working with soap. when I made a call, I used try {} catch {} block. I want to save the exception errors into database. and in order to beautify the codes I parse the errors to my another function here's the sample:

```
$paramis = array(
                'client' => '225',
                'film_id' => '612',
                'booking' => '2016-02-28',
                'persons' => 1
            );
$puri = 'http://www.filmonschedule.com/Portal/break.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($puri, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));
//var_dump($client);

try {
    $resp = $client->__soapCall('getFilmToBook', array('parameters' => $paramis));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    printErrorMu($e);
}

function printErrorMu($e)
{
    print_r($e);
}
```

this is the output printErrorMu($e)

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: No Schedule
   at Portal.Break.getFilmToBook(String portalName, String client, String film_id, String booking, String persons)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/myfilm/test.php
    [line:protected] => 245
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/myfilm/test.php
                    [line] => 245
                    [function] => __soapCall
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => getFilmToBook
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [parameters] => Array
                                        (
                                            [client] => 225
                                            [film_id] => 612
                                            [booking] => 2016-02-28
                                            [persons] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [faultstring] => System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: No Schedule
   at Portal.Break.getFilmToBook(String portalName, String client, String film_id, String booking, String persons
    [faultcode] => soap:Server
    [faultactor] => http://www.filmonschedule.com/Portal/break.asmx
    [detail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [exceptionInfo] => No schedule for this booking request
        )

)
```

but I cannot read the parameter as object/array inside function printErrorMu($e). how to convert the parameter as array or as object so I can access these values of property/key ([message:protected][string:Exception:private][code:protected][file:protected][line:protected][trace:Exception:private][previous:Exception:private]) ?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you cannot? Use the [SoapFault methods](http://php.net/manual/it/class.soapfault.php):

```
$e->getMessage();
$e->getPrevious();
...
```

Comment: Whilst this is correct, it should be worded as an answer ("you should...") not as another question ("why...").

Comment: I could not call $e->getMessage(), $e->getPrevious(), $e->getTrace() inside function printErrorMu().
may be if I pass them as parameters, so it's possible printErrorMu(e->getMessage(), $e->getPrevious(), $e->getTrace()) {}
but that's not what I want

Comment: Why not? SoapFault is an extension of Exception you should be able to call that methods on $e object

Comment: I think you're right. I forgot what the last I did so I couldn't call $e->getMessage() etc, but now it works. thanks